# Eclipse C++: having trouble with including a file with extension ji

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, julia

maybe the title is not the most helpful but wasn't sure how to put it with a few words.
So this is my problem.
I have some C++ projects in Eclipse and I want to use for a part of my project some [Julia](http://julialang.org/) code. 
I have downloaded and installed properly the latest version of Julia on my machine and what I want to do is embed Julia inside my C++ project in Eclipse, so that I will be able to write directly some julia code inside the C++ project.
Such an option is possible and there is [this](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/embedding/) guidance on how to do it.
I do properly in eclipse both the path to include julia.h and the julia library, and I can actually build the project, but when I try to run I receive the following error:

"System image file "/home/kostav/workspace/juli/Debug/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/sys.ji" not found
"

Now this file does exist and its path is included in Eclipse, so I really don't understand why I do receive this error and what should I do in order to fix it.
Any suggestion would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jl_init_with_image

```
jl_init_with_image("pathtosysji", "sys.ji");
```

The path must be the abs path.

ie: /home/kostav/workspace/juli/Debug/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/sys.ji

Comment: Sorry because I am really new in julia you mean that I should create inside the c++ project an julia function that gives the path?
Thing is that I am not sure how to exactly do that

Comment: how are you currently calling julia?

Comment: I just want to run the first small example that is presented in this link http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/embedding/.
So, what I do is that I create a C++ project in Eclipse and copy-pasted this lines and added the library of julia and the path of julia.h to Eclipse in order to link them

Comment: the issue isn't the linking its that it cant find the system image for julia, have you checked it is physically where it is saying it is?

Comment: check my updated answer, `jl_init_with_image` is defined in julia.h (`DLLEXPORT void jl_init_with_image(const char *julia_home_dir, const char *image_relative_path);`)

Comment: as opposed to using jl_init

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot so it works now, so in general every time I want to write julia code in my c++ project I need to initialize via this command, is there no other way to make Eclipse find the image file?