# Execute Julia command from Qt

Tags: qt, julia

I am running Qt (5.2.1) and Julia (v0.3.11) on Ubuntu 14.04 (x64). In a Qt program I can use:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("echo 'Hello'");
```

and get a nice `Hello` printed in the console. But when I try to execute a simple Julia command, something goes wrong:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("julia -e 'println(STDOUT, \"Hello\")'");

if (!process.waitForFinished())
  return;

cout << "Status: " << process.exitStatus() << endl;
```

and the output is simply `Status: 0`.

Why isn't there anything printed in the standard output ?

Note: Julia has been properly installed on my system, and the output of `julia -e 'println(STDOUT, "Hello")'` in the shell is `Hello`, as expected.

Comment: Also check the exit code and stderr/stdout output.I'd also suggest to use the start(QStringList) overload to avoid quoting issues

Comment: Could you try process.start("julia", QStringList() << "-e" << "println..."); ?

Comment: Could you try using execute() rather than start()?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. None of the suggestions worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to embed Julia in Qt by following [this chapter](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/embedding/) of Julia documentation and, most notably, this very useful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051038/eclipse-c-having-trouble-with-including-a-file-with-extension-ji).

The solution is quite different from my initial approach, so let me describe it for completeness.

First, I have modified the `.pro` file to contain:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/ -ljulia
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/julia/
```

Then, I modified `main.cpp` to initialize Julia:

```
...
#include "julia.h"
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Initialize Julia
    jl_init_with_image((char*)"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia", (char*)"sys.ji");
    JL_SET_STACK_BASE;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ...
```

and finally, in a slot function the following command:

```
jl_eval_string((char*)"println(\"Hello\")");
```

did the job !